# Does Tensorflow cache results between session runs?

Tags: tensorflow

I am using the Python API of Tensorflow, and I am profiling my computational graph. Say the end node of the graph is a variable called **tf_v**, I profiled the wall clock run time of **sess.run(tf_v)** 10 times.

I consistently noticed that the first run takes much longer than subsequent runs. Is tensorflow caching results between session runs? (i.e if the input variables values in the graph didn't change, tensorflow returns a cached result from previous run? )